# Little hack: bootstrapdocs.com navbar example (Bootstrap 3.3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'd like to know how to make the dropdown shown on hover instead of on press.
Here is the example:

https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/examples/navbar/

I did try adding:

```
.dropdown:hover + dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

Didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: bootstrap navbar show hide work from JavaScript better way to do it from javascript.
you can call `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle')` on hover function.see the js bootstrap doc https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/javascript/

Comment: Try it `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {`, without the `+` between the classes, and a `.` before the `dropdown-menu`.

Comment: @Sergio here is demo i made http://jsfiddle.net/b130gp72/1/.i think this approach is much safe because display:block is not the only style bootstrap add to toggle menu .it add a class `open`.for example you don't get same menu button color if you just toggle display property

Comment: demo url http://jsfiddle.net/b130gp72/1/

Comment: @Madahawa Priyashantha Thanks for the demo. Intuitively, the CSS solution gives the impression that a conflict can be generated, so I appreciate very much that you have indicated me how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Can you please try this above method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit more to it than the accepted answer. If you also want to highlight the `.dropdown-toggle` background color, you need a few more lines of `CSS`.

[image]

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown:hover > a {
  color: #555;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Without these lines:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy. You are right. I did solve it by my own but it took me a lot to figure out the solution. I should have looked at your comment yesterday :( :P